# performing a Prisma migration on using different schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, automation, prisma

I am working on a project using Prisma where I wanted to make a node module that can be used by other projects. The next step is to keep the DB in sync with the models and the current project as things get updated so all the testing platforms inherit all the changes as automated as possible.

This is the current setup that is working:

- each module has n number of Prisma schemas
- there is a script to copy the schemas from the node modules to the main projects prisma folder
- in the package json, there are commands to generate the Prisma modules from the schema with an output director back in the node modules to be references when needed
- each schema has a different DATABASE_URL

Ideally, there would be something like this in my package json:

"sync-db-1":"npx prisma migrate --schema moduleSchema1.prisma"

"sync-db-2":"npx prisma migrate --schema moduleSchema2.prisma"

And then prisma would perform something like:

- migration -> postgresql://postgres:exmaple@localhost:5432/1
- migration -> postgresql://postgres:exmaple@localhost:5432/2

But currently, Prisma migrate only gets the default schema.prisma file.

Is there any way to update the database like this? I could write a script to iterate through each schema deteted and overwrite the default schema file then run the migrate command over all of them but that is a bit messy and I would like to avoid it if possible.

I checked the documentation on Prisma migration and push and there doesn't seem to be this feature?

Comment: `prisma migrate` supports `--schema` option, no? Would using that switch to provide path to desired schema file work?

Comment: Yea, that is it. it's under the Prisma CLI docs, I guess I was looking in the wrong place. 
This is the link for anyone who comes across this: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-cli-reference#migrate-dev

Answer (score 0):

After validating in the comments that this is indeed relevant, here's an official answer to get this question marked as answered.

Use `prisma migrate --schema` option to point to the desired schema file.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-cli-reference#migrate-dev